# 404 page when trying to access a /media subdirectory file in iframe

Tags: 404-page, iframe

I try to load a pdf file into an `iframe using JavaScript` in a magento page:
My pdf files are stored in `/media/subdirectory.`

I declared a `.htaccess` for my subdirectory in order to allow access, and When i go to the url `www.mysite.com/media/subdirectory/myfile.pdf`, the file is displayed in my browser.

But, when I define this `url as my iframe src, my iframe` loads the 404 page...
(I checked the src url by copy/paste the src url into the browser, and the url is good)

Any idea why?

Comment: Provide the details of the browser on which your are trying. Some browsers wont support iframes.

Comment: same results both on Firefox and Safari

Answer (score 0):

Magento closed `access only to folder downloadable in media folder`. In your case everything should work properly. `Try to check file/folder permissions.`

Comment: directory is 755 and file is 655. What is strange is that i can access the file if I put the iframe src url directly in the browser.

Comment: Show us your iframe code

Comment: <iframe id="deliverypdf-frame" style="display: none;" src="www.xxxxx.fr/media/custom_options/deliverytmp/delivery_100000311_100000057.pdf"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Looking into it a little, there seems to be inconsistencies and issues loading a pdf in an iframe from browser to browser, but possibly some work arounds may work for you.

Take a look at [this answer from a similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19654875/4842324), it may help you out.